# How to add GRAALVM PATH in maven pom file JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have used GRAALVM to compile native JavaFX apps. in commands ports. Here I want to do the same thing using maven.

I have GRAALVM latest version install in C and added the Environment variable as the name GRAALVM_HOME. and in PATH %GRAALVM_HOME%\bin but when I Run client:build-in IntelliJ. it says GRAAL_PATH didn't find.

I tried to do it with the client plugin.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>${client.target}</target>
                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                <bundlesList>
                    <list>com.example.sample.main</list>
                </bundlesList>
                <reflectionList>
                    <list>com.example.sample.MainController</list>
                </reflectionList>
                <graalvmHome>GRAALVM_HOME</graalvmHome>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

inline graalvmhome I set to add the entire path that's didn't work. then I added a GRAALVM_HOME in it. but this didn't work either.

Comment: It solved. I just remove the line graalvmhome and restart my laptop. b/c i realize that I haven't restart it after setting the GRAALVM path. then it's worked

Answer (score 0):

it's `<graalvmHome>path to graal</graalvmHome>` where `path to graal` is the path in your local machine  e.g. /home/user/graal